# CGI script (Perl) running forever under Apache with fastcgi_module

Tags: apache, perl, apache2, cgi, fastcgi

I'm trying to run cgi scripts in Apache2 (Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)) using `fastcgi_module`. This is the virtual host I set up

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName cgi.local
        DocumentRoot /home/noobeana/CGI
        <Directory /home/noobeana/CGI>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                SetHandler fastcgi-script
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the Perl script (properly *775'ed*) I created to run the tests (`/home/noobeana/CGI/test.pl`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello there!<br />\n";
```

The path to the Perl executable is indeed `/usr/bin/perl` and everything else looks fine, but when I open http://cgi.local:8080/test.pl in a browser the script is run forever - I have to stop Apache to force an exit. Also, the `print` is being output to Apache's error log (not the browser), which displays a multitude of the following lines for as long as the script is running:

```
[Fri Feb 07 10:24:54.059738 2014] [:warn] [pid 4708:tid 140365322880896] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/home/noobeana/CGI/test.pl" started (pid 4771)
Content-type: text/html

Hello there!<br />
[Fri Feb 07 10:24:54.078938 2014] [:warn] [pid 4708:tid 140365322880896] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/home/noobeana/CGI/test.pl" (pid 4771) terminated by calling exit with status '0'
[Fri Feb 07 10:24:59.663494 2014] [:warn] [pid 4708:tid 140365322880896] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/home/noobeana/CGI/test.pl" restarted (pid 4773)
Content-type: text/html

Hello there!<br />
[Fri Feb 07 10:24:59.665855 2014] [:warn] [pid 4708:tid 140365322880896] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/home/noobeana/CGI/test.pl" (pid 4773) terminated by calling exit with status '0'
```

I'm not sure whether the two problems (the `print` not being output in the browser and the script not terminating) are related or not.

Comment: CGI and FastCGI are really old-school. You should look instead for modern Perl framework such as [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) and [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/)

Comment: @dolmen: False dichotomy. CGI and FastCGI are interfaces, not frameworks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible. `fastcgi_module` can only run scripts that implement the FastCGI interface, which is not supported by the script you've written. Instead, `fastcgi_module` is repeatedly trying to start your "FastCGI" script, seeing it print some stuff and exit immediately - which FastCGI scripts shouldn't do - and scratching its head wondering what it's doing wrong.

A simple script that *does* implement the correct interface can be implemented using the `CGI::Fast` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use CGI::Fast;
while (my $CGI = CGI::Fast->new) {
    print $CGI->header();
    print "Hello there\n";
}
```

(The FastCGI protocol is somewhat complex, so there's no reasonable way to implement it without using a module.)

Comment: Thanks, @duskwuff. Actually I'm only using Perl to make a simple test, I don't need anything complex. I just need CGI scripts to run under Apache. Maybe I should switch from FastCGI to plain CGI? If I did, do you think my dummy Perl script would run as I expect it to?

Comment: Yes, if this is the case, you should switch to the CGI module.